# How to stay in the same fxml when calling an Alert Class?

Tags: javafx, alert

I have created this methode for Email validation
The issue is that the Alert displayed goes on the top of the previous fxml instead of the same and the user have to fulfill all the fields again

I have this method

```
public boolean validateEmail() {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9._]*@[a-zA-Z0-9]+([.][a-zA-Z]+)+");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(emailField.getText());
    if (m.find() && m.group().equals(emailField.getText())) {
        return true;
    } else {
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.WARNING);
        alert.setTitle("Validation of Email");
        alert.setHeaderText(null);
        alert.setContentText("Please enter a valid Email");
        alert.showAndWait();
        return false;
    }
}
```

I have a button which onAction calls the method below

```
public void showSubscription() throws IOException {
    Dialog<ButtonType> dialog = new Dialog<>();
    dialog.setTitle("New Subscription");
    dialog.setHeaderText("Please Fulfill your information to subscribe");
    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
    fxmlLoader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("Registration.fxml"));

    try {
        dialog.getDialogPane().setContent(fxmlLoader.load());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Couldn't load the Dialog");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }
    dialog.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().add(ButtonType.OK);
    dialog.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().add(ButtonType.CANCEL);

    Optional<ButtonType> result = dialog.showAndWait();
    if (result.isPresent() && result.get()==ButtonType.OK) {
        RegistrationController controller = fxmlLoader.getController();
        if (controller.validateEmail()) {
            controller.loadRegistration();
            Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
            alert.setTitle("Information");
            alert.setHeaderText(null);
            alert.setContentText("Subscription Done Correctly");
            alert.showAndWait();
        }
    }

    else {
        System.out.println("CANCEL pressed");
    }
}
```

I don't know what to add to make this Alert popup in the same Registration.fxml and not go back to the previous one.

Answer (score 0):

`Alert` inherits an `initOwner(Window)` method from `Dialog`. So you can call `initOwner(...)` and pass in the window responsible for showing the dialog. There's no direct reference to this, but you can get it from the scene containing the dialog's dialog pane:

```
alert.initOwner(dialog.getDialogPane().getScene().getWindow());
```

This line just needs to be called sometime before `alert.showAndWait()`.

If you need the `Alert` created in the `validateEmail()` method to have the same owner, just pass a reference to the appropriate window to that method:

```
public boolean validateEmail(Window mainWindow) {

    // ...
    Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.WARNING);
    alert.initOwner(mainWindow);
    // ...
    alert.showAndWait();
    // ...
}
```

and

```
RegistrationController controller = fxmlLoader.getController();
if (controller.validateEmail(dialog.getDialogPane().getScene().getWindow())) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: The 2 codes that I mentioned are in different controller. My dialog is not in the controller where I have my validateEmail. I can't add this line because the dialog is not defined

Comment: Just pass a reference to the window to the `validateEmail()` method?

Comment: @NedraKharbeche I think it would help if you created a [mcve] and edited you question to include it.

Comment: I undertood the problem. After many attempts, I think that the issue was the Dialog. The Dialog itself is a pop-up which can not handle another pop-up on top of it.